# How can I make an item show/hide based on a checkbox being checked/not checked?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, checkbox

So I created a checkbox on my wordpress theme. everything saves properly and all of that:

```
    function member_page_featured_meta() {
        add_meta_box( 'member_page_meta', __( 'Is this a Member Page?', 'member_page-textdomain' ), 'member_page_meta_callback', 'page', 'side', 'low' );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'member_page_featured_meta' );

    /**
     * Outputs the content of the meta box
     */

    function member_page_meta_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'member_page_nonce' );
        $member_page_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
        ?>

     <p>
        <div class="member_page-row-content">
            <label for="featured-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="featured-checkbox" id="featured-checkbox" value="yes" <?php if ( isset ( $member_page_stored_meta['featured-checkbox'] ) ) checked( $member_page_stored_meta['featured-checkbox'][0], 'yes' ); ?> />
                <?php _e( 'Yes', 'member_page-textdomain' )?>
            </label>

        </div>
    </p>   

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Saves the custom meta input
     */
    function member_page_meta_save( $post_id ) {


// Checks save status - overcome autosave, etc.
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'member_page_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'member_page_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';


    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

// Checks for input and saves - save checked as yes and unchecked at no
if( isset( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured-checkbox', 'yes' );
} else {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'featured-checkbox', 'no' );
}

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'member_page_meta_save' );
```

What I need is to make it so that I can use this to show/hide content in Wordpress using Php, but I don't exactly know how to target it in a php if statement.

Do I use the name (featured-checkbox), id (#featured-checkbox), fuction name ($member_page_featured_meta), etc.

And then to make that a specific bit of HTML, how would I want to go about doing that?

HTML/PHP that I am trying to hide when the box is checked.

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div id="membership" "class='false' if not member"></div>
        <div id="phone-answering" "class='false' if not phone client"></div>
        <div id="location-icon" "class='false' if only one location"></div>
    </div>      
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" style="clear:none; font-size: 3em; text-decoration: underline;">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
<div class="entry-content">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#key-intake" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Key Intake</a></li>
            <li><a href="#business-facts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Business Facts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#common-answers" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Common Answers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#understanding" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Understanding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#current" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Current</a></li>
            <li><a href="#location" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#notify" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Notify</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="key-intake" class="">
            <h1  class="tabtitle">Key Intake</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $key_intake_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Key Intake', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $key_intake_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $key_intake_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="business-facts">
        <h1 class="tabtitle">Business Facts</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $business_facts_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Business Facts', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $business_facts_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $business_facts_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="common-answers">
            <h1 class="tabtitle">Common Answers</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $common_answers_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Common Answers', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $common_answers_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $common_answers_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="understanding">
            <h1 class="tabtitle">Understanding</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $understanding_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Understanding', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $understanding_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $understanding_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="current">
            <h1 class="tabtitle">Current</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $current_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Current', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $current_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $current_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="location">
            <h1 class="tabtitle">Locations</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $locations_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Locations', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $locations_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $locations_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="notify">
            <h1 class="tabtitle">Notify</h1>
            <?php 
                // Retrieves the stored value from the database
                $notify_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Notify', true );

                // Checks and displays the retrieved value
                if( !empty( $notify_meta_value ) ) {
                    echo $notify_meta_value;
                } else {
                    echo 'Value Not Fount or Empty';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'odextranet' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Where is the content you want to manipulate? Is it part of the theme or entered into the content editor?

Comment: It is part of the theme. There are a certain few lines of HTML/PHP that I want to show when the box is checked, and not when it is not checked.

Comment: Not the function, the HTML you are trying to show and hide.

Comment: I've added the block of code that I am trying to hide/show.

Comment: And I know that I would surround it with PHP tags to make it work, I just don't know the formatting of the php. I've been working with PHP for about 6 months now, but only on a debugging level. This is the first time I've created anything from scratch.

Comment: Assuming you are getting the correct value for your checkbox, I posted an answer that should tell you what you need to put into the template side.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an inline style to hide and show. You can't target HTML from the PHP so the basic process on the theme side would be:

1. Decide if it should be shown or not.
2. If it should be hidden use a variable to store the inline CSS used to hide the section.
3. Output that variable in the container tag for the section that contains the data to hide or show.

Here is an example that uses some of your code:

```
<?php 
// Retrieves the stored value from the database
$current_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Current', true );

//Will either be empty or contain the inline CSS to hide the content.
$hideOrShow = "";
// Checks and displays the retrieved value
if( !empty( $current_meta_value ) ) {
    $hideOrShow = "display: none;";
}
?>

<div id="content_to_hide_or_show" style="<?php echo $hideOrShow; ?>">
    <!--Content that will be hidden or shown -->
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with the checkbox that I have. I've replaced 'Current' (I'm assuming you took one of the IDs from my HTML code) with 'featured-checkbox' (the ID of my checkbox created in my php function), and it is still not changing. By default, it is hiding.

Comment: is there any way I can use the checked="checked" from my checkbox?

Comment: Actually, let's simplify this. What if I just want to add a class if the checkbox is checked. Say I have a div that has an ID, but not a class. If the checkbox is checked, the class="true", if not checked, the class="false"?

Comment: Are you getting the right value from the check box on the front end?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: Echo out the value.

Comment: It actually is seeming like my save function is not working. No matter what, the value for my checkbox is always "yes"

Comment: I got another look at the code. isset( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] ) will always return true. I believe you want isempty( $_POST[ 'featured-checkbox' ] )